# Force SelectAll on input xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, focus, android-view

So I have a View that has an input and some other layouts. What I would like to do is after the user types something into the input and clicks enter the text in the input to be selected, so he can type again.

The view looks like this.

```
                <CC.AlwaysFocusEditText
                    android:id="@+id/infoArticleEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:theme="@style/ExtendProTheme"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                    android:maxLength="30"
                    local:MvxBind="EnterCommand SearchArticleCommand;Text ArticleCode, Mode=TwoWay; Error Errors['ArticleCode']" />
```

AlwaysFocusEditText is an extended control from EditText so it can execute EnterCommand

```
public class AlwaysFocusEditText : EditText
    {
        public AlwaysFocusEditText(Context c, IAttributeSet a) : base(c, a)
        {
            this.KeyPress += OnEnterKeyPressed;
        }

        public AlwaysFocusEditText(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) :
            base(context, attrs, defStyle)
        {
            this.KeyPress += OnEnterKeyPressed;
        }

        public ICommand EnterCommand { get; set; }

        protected void OnEnterKeyPressed(object sender, View.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (EnterCommand != null)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Android.Views.Keycode.Enter && e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Up)
                {
                    EnterCommand.Execute(null);

                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
                    imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(this.WindowToken, 0);

                    e.Handled = false;

                    var input = (EditText)sender;
                    input.SetSelection(0, input.Text.Length);
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Handled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It looks like this.

I've tried 
1.
  var input = (EditText)sender;
  input.SetSelection(0, input.Text.Length);
2.
  var input = (EditText)sender;
  input.SelectAll();
3. 
  var input = (EditText)sender;
  input.RequestFocus();
  input.SelectAll();

If i make it loose the focus and regain it ( with click ) it works, but it's not what I want. I thought it  must a very simple way that after an even the selected text in an input to be selected.

Can someone please explain to me what am I missing. I'm not that old into android. I thing I'm missing something.

E:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Android.Views.Keycode.Enter && e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Up)
            {
                input.SelectAll();
                e.Handled = false;
            }
```

This works like a charm, but also calling my EnterCommand makes the field loose the select all. I have no idea why.

Edit :

```
  public IMvxCommand SearchArticleCommand => new MvxCommand(async () => await DoThreadAction(SearchArticle));

private async Task SearchArticle()
    {        
        if (IsValid())
        {               
            Article = await _articleService.GetArticleDetails(_articleCode, CurrentAdministration.Id);
        }
    }

protected override bool IsValid()
{
    var validator = new ValidationHelper();
    ArticleCode = ScanHelper.ExtractArticleCode(_articleCode);

    validator.AddRequiredRule(() => ArticleCode, Messages.ArticleCodeRequired);

    var result = validator.ValidateAll();

    Errors = result.AsObservableDictionary();

    return result.IsValid;
}
```

Comment: Please post your `EnterCommand` code.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT added the EnterCommand. What it does it calls for an api endpoint.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT after you said that I should post the code for EnterCommand i looked into IsValid function and the ValidationHelper, it looks like if I remove it, everything works fine.